# How to RDP to my azure cloud service?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

As I read, each azure cloud service has a VM behind it (right?). I know, for a VM, I can click 'Connect' button to get the rdp file to remote login. However, for my cloud service (which is running), the 'Connect' button (in Instance panel) is always disabled. How do I turn it on? How do I remote login to this cloud service?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At first you need to enable remote desktop for your cloud service.
This can be done at least in two ways:

1. During deployment from Visual Studio.
2. Directly at the portal.

I think good way for you know is a second variant.

1. Go to your cloud service.
2. Enter Configure tab and press 'Remote' button at the bottom.
3. Set all the needed settings there (role, user name, password, certificate, expiration etc.).
4. After Azure finishes setup - go to 'Instances' tab. Click on the needed and 'Connect' button will be available.

Comment: Okay, in the meantime, I figured how to do it from Visual Studio. You have to use publish function of the web role project to deploy and there is a checkbox for enabling remote desktop. So far, I only used Configure function for deployment. Thanks for pointing out the second approach which is a better way I think. I wish 'Connect' button is not simply disabled. Instead, it should give you a hint how to enable it.

Comment: At work I usually enable it from Visual Studio, actually. Or enable with powershell scripts - depends on what option i use :) If someone other deploys with obsolete expiration date - then use the portal. For production purposes I disable RDP at all and enable it only in case of urgencies.